# Add a js file and be sure it is executed as last js file?

Tags: 7, javascript

I need to add a js file and make it to be executed as last js file (after all js that belong to modules)

I create a module for this. But I can't manage the order of modules execution. Don't I?
¿should I add this file in my theme or through a function instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`drupal_add_js`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) you can control the order of your JS files by assigning weight through `$options` array.

> **weight**: A number defining the order in which the JavaScript is added
>   to the page relative to other JavaScript with the same 'scope',
>   'group', and 'every_page' value.
>
> The exact ordering of JavaScript is
>   as follows:
>
> 1. First by scope, with 'header' first, 'footer' last, and
>      any other scopes provided by a custom theme coming in between, as
>      determined by the theme.
> 2. Then by group.
> 3. Then by the 'every_page' flag,
>      with TRUE coming before FALSE.
> 4. Then by weight.
> 5. Then by the order in
>      which the JavaScript was added. For example, all else being the same,
>      JavaScript added by a call to drupal_add_js() that happened later in
>      the page request gets added to the page after one for which
>      drupal_add_js() happened earlier in the page request.

Code example:

```
drupal_add_js($file_path, array(
  'weight' => 10000, // Something higher than the weight of existing items
  'scope' => 'footer', // Make sure the script tag is rendered in the footer of the page, not the header
  'group' => JS_THEME, // JS_THEME has the highest group weight and will be rendered last
));
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind I merged the code from my answer with this, didn't seem any sense in keeping them both...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to guarantee that it is the last thing done, you really need to work outside of the Drupal behaviors.  You can still *load* the file wherever you want, but you need to do something slightly different.

Drupal behaviors fire as part of a `$(document).ready()`.  The only way to guarantee that your function will be last is to use a later event like `$(window).load()`, eg

```
(function ($, Drupal, undefined) {
  $(window).load(function () {
    do_something_awesome();
  });
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Comment: But how does that prevent another function that binds to $(window).load() from running after this code? You would _have_ to make sure the file is last to be loaded into the HTML. Plus deferring JS until the entire document (and all images) have downloaded is not a good trade off IMO

Comment: @Clive Yes, correct on all counts.  Relying on execution order for anything is a bad idea, and should be avoided is possible as it is a fragile beast.  This solution does assume that nobody remembers that you can use $(window).load() to do things :)  While is does delay things, it can help speeds up page loads when you need to load *a lot* of assets (eg, lots of XML or JSON for a web app), because your assets won't clog up the loading queue for general JS, CSS, and images.  This is the only time I still use $(window).load() by choice.